# Dynamic Polymorphic Lightning Components

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, polymorphism, oop

I have a Parent component rendering child components. I want this to happen dynamically, meaning that I can pass in a child component definition and fill it with data afterwards.

```
<!--c:child-->
<aura:component extends="c:abstractChild">
    Hello World
</aura:component>

<!--c:parent-->
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="child" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
    {!v.child}
</aura:component>

<!--c:container-->
<aura:component>
    <c:parent>
        <aura:set attribute="child" >
            <c:child />
        </aura:set>
    </c:parent>
</aura:component>
```

It works fine. Now I want something like this:

```
<!--c:child-->
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="fooBar" type="Object" />
    {!v.fooBar}
</aura:component>

<!--c:parent-->
<aura:component>
    <aura:attribute name="child" type="Aura.Component[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="fooBarList" type="Object"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.fooBarList}" var="fooBar">
        {!v.child}
        <!--<aura:set attribute="fooBar" value="{!fooBar}"/>-->
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

(The fact that I need it in a loop is important. So I can't set the attribute in my component controller.)

**How do I set attributes for this child in my Parent component?**

`type="Aura.Component[]"` is not typed, can I pass in something like a typed component? Or do anything to convert attributes back to components?

Pseudo code:

```
<aura:attribute name="child" type="c:child"/>

<aura:dynamic component="{v.child}">
    <aura:set attribute="fooBar" value="{!fooBar}"/>
</aura:dynamic>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm totally missing what you're trying to do here, I think you need to use `$A.createComponents()` to create them dynamically from the controller/helper of `c:parent`.

`c:parent` could take a list of objects describing what it needs to create e.g.

```
spec = [ {type: 'c:Child1', attr1: 'foo'}, {type: 'c:Child2', attr2: 'bar'} ]
```

Then, in the parent, do something like this:

```
var componentArray = [];
spec.forEach(function (thisSpec) {
  componentArray.push([thisSpec.type, thisSpec]);
});

$A.createComponents(componentArray, function(newComponents, status) {
  if(status === 'SUCCESS') {
    var body = component.get('v.body');
    body = body.concat(newComponents);
    component.set('v.body', body);
  }
});
```

You can later check that the children are instances of `c:abstractChild` by using `component.isInstanceOf('c:abstractChild')`

Disclaimer: I haven't run that code, but I have production code doing roughly the same thing, so it ought to at least give you the gist of what to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but creating the components in the controller won't work for me, since $A.createComponents just creates them, but I have a complex structure (table), that needs to be rendered in the markup.
Else I would have to run through the whole data and replace it with component definitions.

Comment: It's up to you to decide where you insert the dynamic components after they are created. They don't just have to replace the body - you could find some part of a table and insert them there. Or you could put in placeholders with aura:iterations, then overwrite them once you've created the right type. Can you add to your question to explain why the table part is significant?

Comment: Well I'm having a table with rows, columns and summaries all of them containing cells or at least references and I don't want to duplicate this structure to rerender the markup. It just feels to dirty, I wouldn't need an OOP approach, when I start hacking things in my controller. I really appreciate your contribution and it triggers new thoughts, but doing all the important stuff in the controller is not an option for me.